# Proving a binary tree

Tags: binary-tree, discrete-mathematics, proof

How would i go about proving the relationship with `j` and `k` if `T` is a binary tree with `k` internal vertices and `j` terminal vertices

In a full binary tee I know that `j = k + 1`

In a binary tree that is not full I know that `j = k` if there are an odd number of vertices with one child and `j = k  - 1` if there are an even number of vertices with one child.

I am not sure how to go about the proving process though.

Answer (score 0):

The total number of nodes in a complete binary tree of depth `d` equals 2<sup>(d+1)</sup> – 1. Since all leaves in such a tree are at level `d`, the tree contains 2<sup>d</sup> leaves and, therefore, 2<sup>d</sup> - 1 internal nodes. and you can use this to prove the other one.